# AWS LambdaからLineAPIの利用

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws, aws-lambda

お世話になっております。

AWS Lambdaを利用して、Node.jsでLINE APIをたたいているのですが、
ステータスコード 403 が出てしまいます。

何か解決策はありますでしょうか。

ソースが下記になります。

```
var https = require('https');
//line  url
var url = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply";

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

var msg = event.body;
var jsonTest = JSON.parse(event.body).events;

// Request Body
var request_body = JSON.stringify({
  "replyToken": "\"" + jsonTest[0].replyToken + "\"",
  "messages":[
            {
                "type":"text",
                "text":"test"
            }
        ]
});

console.log('通過しました２。');

var opts = {
    host: 'api.line.me',
    path: '/v2/bot/message/reply',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Length": request_body.length,
        "Authorization": "Bearer {LINE の ChannelToken}"
    },
    method: 'POST'
};

// APIリクエスト
var req = https.request(opts, function(res){
    console.log('通過しましたリクエスト。');
    res.on('request_body', function (chunk) {
        console.log('リクエスト成功。');
        console.log(res.statusCode + chunk.toString());
    });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('リクエスト失敗');
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message);
    });

    console.log(res.statusCode);

});


console.log('通過しました３。');
req.write(request_body);
console.log('通過しました４。');
req.end();
console.log('通過しました５。');
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "replyToken": "\"" + jsonTest[0].replyToken + "\"",

この部分がおかしいです。

```
"replyToken": jsonTest[0].replyToken
```

とダブルクオーテーションでくくってやらなくてもJSON.stringifyがうまくやってくれます。
エスケープしたダブルクオーテーションを含めてしまうと、余計なものがついてしまい無効なtokenが生成されてしまいます。

```js
var replyToken = "aaabbbccc"
var request_body = JSON.stringify({
  "replyToken": "\"" + replyToken + "\"",
  "messages":[
            {
                "type":"text",
                "text":"test"
            }
        ]
});

console.log(request_body)
```

https://devdocs.line.me/ja/#common-specifications

> 403 Forbidden     APIの利用権限がありません。ご契約中のプランやアカウントに付与された権限を確認してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。指摘にあるように、トークンの部分が間違っておりました。無事、メッセージを送ることができました。ありがとうございます。